# How to make spring boot use my mongodb codec when reading a document

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to use MongoDB and Spring Data Mongodb alongside with ZonedDateTime.

For this, I am using one of [these](https://github.com/cbartosiak/bson-codecs-jsr310), `ZonedDateTimeAsDocumentCodec`. I registered it with this little piece of configuration, alongside with default codecs

```kotlin
 @Bean
    fun zonedDateTimeCodecCustomizer() = MongoClientSettingsBuilderCustomizer { clientSettingsBuilder ->
        clientSettingsBuilder.codecRegistry(
            CodecRegistries.fromRegistries(
                MongoClientSettings.getDefaultCodecRegistry(),
                CodecRegistries.fromCodecs(
                    ZonedDateTimeAsDocumentCodec()
                )
            )
        )
    }
```

When storing an object with a `ZonedDateTime` field, it works well, but I am trying to read the same object, got an error : `java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make private java.time.ZonedDateTime(java.time.LocalDateTime,java.time.ZoneOffset,java.time.ZoneId) accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.time" to unnamed module @11bb571c`

I did a little dive in the code, and it seems that Spring Data only use codec after trying to create a persistent entity of the field, and in doing so, it try to make the constructor accessible. Which cannot work, throw an exception and all the process into the crapper.

Any lead on how to make Spring Data jumping directly to codec use for ZonedDateTime ?

P.S. : I know I have some workaround to my problem (Spring Converter being one) but I would like to stick to codec if possible.

Comment: The error message Sounds very "java 8to9 update specific" (modules..) Do you: fork/copy&paste it or use the released artifact? (Maven central) 1 con: this repo was last updated 3 years ago, bson - 10 days ago ;(

Comment: I juste checked the code. problem come from `org.springframework.data.mapping.
.PreferredConstructor`which try to call `org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible`, which is marked as deprecated for Java 9. I will check more recent version of spring data.